# Display default map (world map) using jQuery Leaflet map

Tags: jquery

How to show the simple default map (world map) when there is no data present by using leaflet maps plugin.

Comment: Do you mean so that the whole world (not a specific location) is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Quick Start Guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/), make sure you include the Leaflet CSS in the `<head>`of your document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
```

and include a call to the Leaflet JavaScript file, usually at the end inside your `<body>` tag

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

and put a `<div>` element **where you want your map** to be. In this case, you can use the following, to display a world map with no data.

```
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 330px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([40, 0], 1);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

</script>
```

`setView([40,0],` is lat/lon `1);` is zoom level (whole world)
Everything following `L.tileLayer` just references a basic tile layer, in this case a CC-attributed one from Mapbox but any generic tilelayer hosted online should work here as well.